# OnLoad for webpacks build.js?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webpack

I receive a build.js generated with webpack from other department. I include it in the HTML file with

`<script type="module" src="build.js"></script>`

But there are a number of asynchronous requests and variables in there that I need to access. I cannot access them until the build.js is completely loaded. How can I check when it has been loaded?

Comment: The `load` event on the window should guarantee that that file has loaded.  It does not necessarily guarantee anything about the state (or existance) of any asynchronous logic in the file itself.

Comment: @Taplar I think the question is not only about loading a js file, but about loading some third-party resources via requests sent by the code in that file as well.

Comment: `<script>` is an html tag, and the src on it is a `*.js` file.  I'm not sure how it could be confused as to what the user is doing.  @LajosArpad

Comment: @Taplar the user is not waiting for the script to be loaded. He waits for the script's asynchronous requests to be completed, as the question clearly states: "But there are a number of asynchronous requests and variables in there that I need to access." The question at the end is misleading "How can I check when it has been loaded?", which, in my opinion is the cause of misunderstanding the question. What the asker really means by "completely loaded" AFAIK is that all the asynchronous requests issued from build.js were successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

If build.js is your code and you are comfortable in editing it, then you could create a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which would automatically be fulfilled when the asynchronous tasks are completed. You can also use multiple promises and call [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to ensure that all your variables are in place.

Example for `Promise.all`, taken from the documentation:

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

If build.js is not something you are comfortable modifying, then you could read it or its documentation and find out whether there is an even hook for the event when its loading is completed.

If all else fails, then you can use `setInterval` to repeatedly check for all the resources that you need and once they are found, perform the operations you need along with `clearInterval` to stop the repeated check for them.